# Can a RewriteRule process the `-` operator?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I set up the following rule in my `htaccess`:

`RewriteRule ^abc/\w+/xyz/?$ /go.php [L]`

I noticed that it would work for:

`abc/hello/xyz/`

`abc/hello_there/xyz/`

But will yield 404 if I try:

`abc/hello-there/xyz/`

Therefore, is there a way to modify the rule so it would read `-` operator as well? why does it happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you didn't include the `-` in your regex. `\w` is short for `A-Za-z0-9_` so if you want to include a `-` you need to add it to the expression.

```
RewriteRule ^abc/[\w-]+/xyz/?$ /go.php [L]
```

Comment: Ok nice. Can using this new form have any side-effects? or everything will work as before, just that from now on, URLs with `-` will work properly as well?

Comment: Correct, everything is as before. it just now handles the - in the URL so it works properly.

Comment: When it works out for you please be sure to accept the answer.